# table not fitting

Tags: tables

Ciao guys, I need to make the table below have certain properties
 To fit onto the page. And then making the columns evenly spaced even if it means breaking up the long column label.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} %
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Descriptive statistics of country-level yearly covariates}
    \begin{tabular}{rccc|ccc}
    \addlinespace
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Countries experiencing spont. events of disturbance } & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Countries not experiencing spont. events of disturbance } \\
    \midrule
          & Obs   & Mean  & Std Dev. & Obs   & Mean  & Std. Dev \\
                    \hline
    Urban population (percent) & 525   & 32.527 & 13.186 & 273   & 30.994 & 11.883 \\
    GDP per capita (constant, USD, year 2000) & 462   & 643.516 & 700.011 & 270   & 488.737 & 480.186 \\
    Democracy indicator (Binary) & 474   & 0.409 & 0.492 & 242   & 0.178 & 0.383 \\
    Internet penetration (users/100 of population) & 418   & 2.739 & 4.598 & 213   & 2.916 & 5.954 \\
    Cellphone subscribers (users/100 of population) & 524   & 10.857 & 20.657 & 270   & 12.015 & 24.364 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{covariates}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way to get the table to fit:

- Use `>{\raggedright}m{3.0cm}` for the first column. This make the column a fixed width, and centers the content vertically.
- Split the header over several rows.
- I also added `\hrule` to make the rows stand out.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} %
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Descriptive statistics of country-level yearly covariates}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}m{3.0cm}ccc|ccc}
    \addlinespace
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Countries experiencing} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Countries not experiencing} \\
          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{spont. events } & \multicolumn{3}{c}{spont. events} \\
          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{of disturbance } & \multicolumn{3}{c}{of disturbance } \\
    \midrule
          & Obs   & Mean  & Std Dev. & Obs   & Mean  & Std. Dev \\
                    \hline
    Urban population (percent) & 525   & 32.527 & 13.186 & 273   & 30.994 & 11.883 \\\hrule
    GDP per capita (constant, USD, year 2000) & 462   & 643.516 & 700.011 & 270   & 488.737 & 480.186 \\\hrule
    Democracy indicator (Binary) & 474   & 0.409 & 0.492 & 242   & 0.178 & 0.383 \\\hrule
    Internet penetration (users/100 of population) & 418   & 2.739 & 4.598 & 213   & 2.916 & 5.954 \\\hrule
    Cellphone subscribers (users/100 of population) & 524   & 10.857 & 20.657 & 270   & 12.015 & 24.364 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{covariates}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very nice, just one more little thing. Rather than using \hrule, is it possible to increase the spacing between the rows to make them stand out?

Comment: You can try `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}`.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I also found a solution; a simple backlash instead of \hline plus a blank line:-)

Comment: Instead of `\hrule`, you could also use `\cmidrule{1-1}`. Doing so will automatically add a nice amount of vertical "breathing space" above and below the rule.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} %
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\RaggedRight}Xcrr|crr @{}}
    \addlinespace
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{3}{p{4.75cm}}{\RaggedRight Countries experiencing spont. events of disturbance}
          & \multicolumn{3}{p{5cm}}{\RaggedRight Countries not experiencing spont. events of disturbance } \\
    \midrule
          & Obs   & Mean  & Std Dev. & Obs   & Mean  & Std. Dev \\
                    \hline
    Urban population (percent) & 525   & 32.527 & 13.186 & 273   & 30.994 & 11.883 \\\hrule
    GDP per capita (constant, USD, year 2000) & 462   & 643.516 & 700.011 & 270   & 488.737 & 480.186 \\\hrule
    Democracy indicator (Binary) & 474   & 0.409 & 0.492 & 242   & 0.178 & 0.383 \\\hrule
    Internet penetration (users/100 of population) & 418   & 2.739 & 4.598 & 213   & 2.916 & 5.954 \\\hrule
    Cellphone subscribers (users/100 of population) & 524   & 10.857 & 20.657 & 270   & 12.015 & 24.364 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%

\end{document}
```

[image]